# GitHub - commits are pushed with different username based on origin computer

Tags: git, github

I have 2 computers and use different user account (in terms of OS account, not GitHub) on each of them. I set up SSH keys on both of them but If I commit/push from one computer, in GitHub project's page I can see that "userA" is author of the commit. But If I commit/push from the 2nd one, name of OS user account is used as author of the commit. How can I fix it and have only one commit's author?

Perhaps a better would be to show example. [Here](https://github.com/ladariha/synergy/commits/master) is a list of commits, all made by me. The "vriha" is incorrect and "ladariha" is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it your desire to have both usernames hyperlinked to your GitHub account, then you should know that GitHub disambiguates users on the user.email configuration setting. So update in both repositories accordingly, and they will be subsequently hyperlinked. Source: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git

Answer (score 2):

Try `git config --global user.name "ladariha"`